# Correctly write comparison operator for references

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I have the code:

```
#include <vector>

#define DECK_SIZE 52

struct Card {
    int Value;
    int Suit;

    bool operator == (Card &c1) {
        return ((Value == c1.Value) && (Suit == c1.Suit));
    }
};

typedef std::vector<Card> hand_t;

bool IsCardInHand(const Card & checkCard, const hand_t & hand)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(hand.size()); ++i) {
        if (checkCard == hand[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This line: `if (checkCard == hand[i])` is generated an error: `IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands` of IntelliSense and `error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Card' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` of the compiler (Visual C++ 2010).

Please, help, how can I rewrite `operator==` correctly?

Comment: Note that once you fix `operator==`, you can rewrite `IsCardInHand()` to just be `return std::find(hand.begin(), hand.end(), checkCard) != hand.end();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need (note the consts):

```
bool operator == (const Card &c1) const {
```

Comment: Thank you :-) It was obvious, my leaky head :(

Comment: Well it's morning in my part of the world, so you can have that as your excuse. :)